# Installing necessary shared library dependencies for puppeteer in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, puppeteer

First of all my knowledge of docker is limited. This is my problem: I cannot get puppeteer running in my deployed container. The requests I make to the end points of my service end up timing out.

I've tried to include the following https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker in my dockerfile to try and make it work. I tried multiple variations but based on trial and error, since I don't have any in depts knowledge of how things actually work.

This the current Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.9.4

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 \
    libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 \
    libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 \
    libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixesx3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 \
    fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst ttf-freefont \
    ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget && \
    wget https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.1/dumb-init_1.2.1_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i dumb-init_*.deb && rm -f dumb-init_*.deb && \
    apt-get clean && apt-get autoremove -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app

COPY . /opt/app

RUN groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser

ENV LANG="C.UTF-8"

WORKDIR /opt/app

RUN cd /opt/app
RUN \
    npm install -g typescript && \
    npm install pm2 -g -y

RUN npm i \
    npm i puppeteer \
    # Add user so we don't need --no-sandbox.
    # same layer as npm install to keep re-chowned files from using up several hundred MBs more space
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /opt/app/node_modules

RUN npm run build

USER pptruser

ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]
EXPOSE 3600
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "pm2.json", "google-chrome-unstable" ]
```

The service should generate some html and generate an image file using puppeteer. Is there anyone that can help me out?

Comment: what is the quesion, what are the error ?

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear. There is no error during the build just a time out when trying to use an endpoint that should use puppeteer to create a screenshot. Based on the documentation and researching similar behaviour on the web the problem should be that the shared libraries are not setup correctly and therefor puppeteer cannot start up properly but there are no errors visible and the end point just times out. Locally the end point works properly. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Are you trying to add them on AWS?

Comment: Yes I am. Does it require different configuration?